# How to use spring cloud kubernetes discovery on localhost?

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery

I replaced Eureka service with Spring Cloud Kubernetes Discovery to run in kubernetes cluster (microk8s) and it's work fine in k8s without eurika. But how can i use Spring Cloud Kubernetes Discovery for local debug? For example, when  i'm starting my microservices local without kubernetes, how can I resolve them by name? Is't necessary to use any local discovery service like Eurika in that case? or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

simple way can be to create a network of services via docker-compose file and run docker containers for the applications those need to be communicate with and the main services those you need to debug can be opened in the VSCode like editors.

The service discovery can happen by help of docker-compose and eureka or spring-cloud won't be required.